# Make UserControl Visible after Logging In

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, asp.net-ajax, master-pages

I have a popup login usercontrol in a masterpage, once logged in I want another usercontrol on a content page to appear automatically, currently it only appears if I manually refresh the page. How can this be accomplished. Thanks.

MasterPage - > login usercontrol

View.aspx - > bookmark usercontrol (should appear after logging in)

login usercontrol in Master Page

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="login" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">     
           <ContentTemplate>    
               <asp:Panel ID="pnlLogin" runat="server">
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password </asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Button ID="btbookmark" runat="server" Text="Login"   OnClick="btbookmark_Click"/>  
          </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlData" runat="server">Placeholder for bookmark data. Bookmark data goes here.
</asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Bookmark usercontrol on View.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbookmark" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Button ID="btmark" runat="server" />
```

After logging in how can the Bookmark usercontrol on View.aspx appear. Do I need to use an updatepanel?

Answer (score 0):

You could either register it and set the Visible property to false in the code behind, until the user has logged in, and then you set the property to true. You will need to add code to prevent a lot of processing if the user session object doesn't exist.

aspx:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="control" TagName="UserBookmarks" Src="~UserBookmarks.ascx" %>
<control:UserBookMarks ID="UserBookmarksCtrl" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

code behind:

```
// If user logged in
UserBookmarksCtrl.Visible = True
```

Or, you can dynamically create the control, and add it to your page once a user has logged in (i.e. something like Session["user"] has been set).

Comment: How can the bookmark control appear with refreshing the page?

Comment: @Aron It is possible that the code behind is checking for !IsPostBack before setting the property Visible to true. Also, be aware of the page life cycle, and the auto wired events such as Page_Load, Page_LoadComplete, Page_PreRender etc.  These are usually called in order: page, master page, user control in page, user controls in master page. Also, the events wired for controls depend on the order the controls appear on a given page. Without seeing code, it's hard to determine what is going on.

Comment: That sounds like my problem the login usercontrol in the masterpage which creates the session is executed after the page bookmark control which I want to change to change to visible. Suggestions?

Comment: You could move the logic in the page and control in the page in Page_PreRender instead of Page_Load, this will push the events down. Also, you can expose methods publicly and not rely on the autowired events.